# Another Number Sequence Problem

Tags: number-sequence

Find the next number in the sequence:

$10,11,21,32,53,85,49,45,5,50,?$

This sequence seems to me as possibly difficult to guess, so below is a hint.

> The sequence is about remainders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let me try...

> (10 + 11) % 89 = 21 % 89 = **21**
>  (11 + 21) % 89 = 32 % 89 = **32**
>  (21 + 32) % 89 = 53 % 89 = **53**
>  (32 + 53) % 89 = 85 % 89 = **85**
>  (53 + 85) % 89 = 138 % 89 = **49**
>  (85 + 49) % 89 = 134 % 89 = **45**
>  (49 + 45) % 89 = 94 % 89 = **5**
>  (45 + 5) % 89 = 50 % 89 = **50**

So, the next one should be...

> (5 + 50) % 89 = 55 % 89 = **55**

Comment: That is correct! I was thinking of $10^n\% 89$, but your pattern also works.

Comment: $10^n~\%~89 = 100 \times 10^{n-2}~\%~89 = 11 \times 10^{n-2}~\%~89 = (10^{n-1} + 10^{n-2})~\% 89$

Comment: I noticed that when I thought about why your solution worked. If I had seen that pattern, I could have computed the terms so much easier...